# Detecting touch patterns and associating them with info

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, touch

i want to make an android app that detects touch patterns and associates them with info 
EG: 3 touch points with specific distance
Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MotionEvent Object documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html).
Check [this training](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html) provided by Google on how to detect multiple touches

More specifically:

> ```
> // The coordinates of the current screen contact, relative to 
> // the responding View or Activity.  
> xPos = (int)MotionEventCompat.getX(event, index);
> yPos = (int)MotionEventCompat.getY(event, index);
> ```